# An Enigmatic Price List

Tags: knowledge, pattern

```
Item #     Price
------    ------
   1       $1.25
   3       $2.05
   7      $20.00
  16       $5.01
  18      $50.00
  32       $0.10
  34       $1.00
  35       $0.50
```

What are these items and how are their prices determined?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These historical items are

> US Presidents in order of office

And the values are

> 01) 1.25  - George Washington on a dollar and a quarter
>  03) 2.05  - Thomas Jefferson on the 2 dollar bill and a nickel
>  07) 20.00 - Andrew Jackson on the 20 dollar bill
>  16) 5.01 - Abe Lincoln on the 5 dollar bill and a penny
>  18) 50.00 - Ulysses S. Grant on the 50 dollar bill
>  32) 0.10 - Franklin Roosevelt on the dime
>  34) 1.00 - Dwight Eisenhower on the dollar coin
>  35) 0.50  - John F. Kennedy on the half-dollar

Comment: That just leaves Hamilton $10 all by himself. So is it 0 = 10?

Comment: He's probably chillin' with Sacagawea at 0 = 1. Or 0 = 11 maybe? There are probably more but she should probably count, too.